# Show Laravel resources API for only specific routes

Tags: laravel, api

Is it possible to show new added Laravel resources API fields on specific routes?

***Example:*** I have a `UserResource` which has 3 fields - `id, name and email`. I'm returning `UserResource` in 10 routes. For 11th route added new field - `posts`.

Is it possible to show new `posts` field only for 11th route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, so you need to add two things. First inside of your controller in the method where you want to load posts do the following

```
return UserResourse::collection($users->with('posts'));
```

Then inside of your `UserResourse` class add the following

```
'posts' => PostResourse::collection($this->whenLoaded('posts'))
 // or like this if you dont have a PostResouse
'posts' => $this->posts
```

Comment: For single record: `return UserResource($user->loadMissing(['posts']));`

Comment: No nead just run return new UserResource($user->with('posts'))